# Junção de Selects SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Tenho os seguintes selects, mas preciso que sejam retornado esses dados juntos, unindo os selects alguém sugere algo?

```
SELECT 
COUNT(numero_parcela) as 'total_parcelas',
SUM(valor_original) as 'valor_original', 
SUM(valor_pago) as 'valor_pago' 
FROM financeiro.contas_receber 
WHERE id_cliente = 247

SELECT 
COUNT (numero_parcela) as 'parcelas_atraso', 
SUM(valor_original) as 'valor_atraso'
FROM financeiro.contas_receber
WHERE id_cliente = 247 and data_vencimento < GETDATE()
```

desde de já agradeço

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar as duas opções abaixo, eu utilizaria a primeira opção, pois é a mesma tabela, assim evitando processamento desnecessário:

**CASE WHEN:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(numero_parcela) as 'total_parcelas',
    SUM(valor_original) as 'valor_original', 
    SUM(valor_pago) as 'valor_pago',
    SUM(CASE WHEN data_vencimento < GETDATE() THEN valor_origianl ELSE 0 END) as 'valor_atraso'
FROM financeiro.contas_receber 
WHERE id_cliente = 247
```

**CROSS JOIN:**

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(a.numero_parcela) as 'total_parcelas',
    SUM(a.valor_original) as 'valor_original', 
    SUM(a.valor_pago) as 'valor_pago',
    b.parcelas_atraso,
    b.valor_atraso
FROM financeiro.contas_receber as a
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        COUNT (numero_parcela) as 'parcelas_atraso', 
        SUM(valor_original) as 'valor_atraso'
    FROM financeiro.contas_receber
    WHERE id_cliente = 247 and data_vencimento < GETDATE()
) as b
WHERE a.id_cliente = 247
```

Comment: você me deu o caminho!, vou só fazer alguns ajustes e acredito que vai dar certo! muito obrigago